# Can't close "Open with.." dialog when there's no suitable application installed in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, xdg, kde-apps

Clicking file that doesn't have associated program is an annoying problem in KDE. It opens a window that can't be closed easily [even with sudo pkill].

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Download a file with no associated program installed through Firefox using `xdg-desktop-portal-kde`.
2. Open it through the browser.

**OBSERVED RESULT**

An unclosable dialog will open with no suggestions. The "Show More" button will help if a suitable program is installed but not set, but it won't if you'd have to install it manually.
I've also tested and does not happen in chromium, it opens the same KIO dialog Dolphin does.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

Be able to close the dialog, install a suitable program elsewhere, and then try again.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Also there's an horizontal scrollbar at all times, even though there is no content.

***This should be fixed now with changes in Plasma 5.25.*** [[ Source ]](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450930)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For those who can't close "Open with.." dialog window.

**Solution:**

1. Right Click on "Open with.." dialog window's title bar.
2. Choose "Configure Special Window Settings" from "More Action".
3. Click "Add Property.." from bottom.
4. Add `closeable` option.
5. Choose `closeable` as "yes".
6. Now you can turn close the window.

Comment: You saved my day!!

Comment: It seems like not being closeable is a pretty silly default setting.

Comment: Agree. They said it would be fixed and there are many things that need to be set to default too (a double-tap on the touchpad should be counted as a left click, and many more).

Comment: Thanks! The more I learn about KDE, the more I love it. Imagine is this kind of setting was configurable in all OSs.